# Cannot see the values are entered with React.js in Iphone

Tags: html, reactjs, safari

I have some problems when I try to use my **React.js app in my iphone** . The input in my Iphone which **cannot show me the values** that **were inputted** to the HTML input, I tried to use on other Iphone, then I have the same result. This case not only in Safari but also on Google Chrome on my phone. In contrast, android phone had a different result which I could see my typing. Below is the picture that I cannot see the input value on my phone.

**Thank you all.**

[image: Image of the problem]

Comment: Please provide your app manifest.

Comment: @LMichiels  can you give me an example? Thank you very much